# MtGox-Api License

Tags: mtgox, legal

I want to use the data of the MtGox-API for my (commercial) website. I want to show their data as an exchange-rate, but, of course, I will link to their site and cite them as source. I couldn't find anything on their site about the usage of the API-Data for a commercial site, so... does anyone know about that?

Comment: How about contacting @magicaltux on twitter and ask them directly? MtGox owner usually answers questions.

Answer (score 2):

I emailed them and the answer was:

> Hello,
>
> That is fine. We have no restrictions at the moment.
>
> Thanks,
>
> MtGox.com Team

So that's pretty awesome!